# Parse html in php issue

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I am writing html code for tcpdf.I have description saved in mysql with html tags.how can I read it in php. For example:

```
$description = "Brand new!!! <br /><br /><br />Huge size";
$html = '<div>'. $description.'</div>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

It shows description as it is.I need to implement html tags(come to new line three times)

I tried but no luck

```
$description  = htmlspecialchars($rw['description_demo']);
```

Output should be like

> Brand new!!!
>   Huge size

when I use `echo $html` it also give me same issue.

Comment: I assume that the parse error is a typo in the code you've posted here :-? You've showed the expected output. What's the actual output?

Comment: actual output is Brand new!!! <br /><br /><br />Huge size

Comment: Try newline characters

Comment: this is created in tinymce and saved in mysql....i can not change more than 10000000 records to newline ...

Comment: @user2244804 - Yes, you can. Write a single code that makes the change and put it inside the loop that reads the DB results.

Comment: it should be `$html = '<div>'.$description.'</div>';`

Comment: @Amir yes this was typing mistake..i need solution which solve for all tags not only <br />

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `<br>` try below code if it is helpful to you

```
$pdf->InsertText("Line one\n\nLine two");
```

or if you wish to remove html tag

```
$string = 'A string with <br/> & "double quotes".';
$string = str_replace(array('<br/>', '&', '"'), ' ', $string);
echo $string;
```

Comment: A whole html is created for a page at once.this is not possible...i need some php command to execute html tags not to print as it is

Comment: Not usefull,From where \n\n came?i am saying i have already saved text which has <br/>

Comment: I haven't tested it but I'd assume that `writeHTML()` handles input as HTML and, us such, should ignore line feeds :-?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about current release of TCPDF but most HTML to PDF libraries implement their own HTML parser and they often fail to recognise fairly common tags. Particularly, I've personally used libraries that would not accept self closing tags like `<br />`. I suggest you try with `<br>`.

If the HTML code is generated by a third-party tool, a simple `str_replace('<br />', '<br>', $html)` could be a quick and dirty fix.

**Edit:** Apparently, we're now talking about replacing *all* unsupported tags. That's a major task. You'll need to use DOMDocument or the parser of your choice—brute force string based HTML manipulation is likely to trigger invalid results sooner or later.

Other alternative is to switch to a PDF tool with better HTML support, such as [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) (a command line program you need to install) or [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) (a PHP library).

Comment: THis is usful but not a solution.bcoz there must be other alot of tags so i need some thing to solve problem for all

Comment: @user2244804 perhaps `str_replace('/>', '>', $html)` is better

Comment: Perhaps it isn't a solution for your *problem* but (assuming it actually works) it's definitively a solution for you *question* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing <br /> to <br/>:

```
$description = "Brand new!!! <br /><br /><br />Huge size";
$html = '<div>.' $description'.</div>';
$pdf->writeHTML(str_replace('<br />', '<br/>', $html), true, false, true, false, '');
```

But keep in mind that tcpdf has limited support for html tags.

If you want to generate pdf from html I suggest using [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) - it using the webkit rendering engine, so you shouldn't have problem to generate pdf with your descriptions.